# WebGL unavailable on Chrome for no apparent reason

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm not entirely sure when this issue started, it could have been after a graphics card driver update, but WebGL will no longer function for me on Chrome.

http://webglreport.com/ tells me that

> This browser supports WebGL, but it is disabled or unavailable.

I have a custom-built Windows computer with a GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST. My drivers are up to date (Geforce 337.88). Chrome is the latest version as well, 35.0.1916.153. Going to chrome://gpu/ gives this information:

> WebGL: Hardware accelerated

However, if I scroll further down to the logs, I see this error message repeated hundreds of times:

> [10800:10804:0714/120136:ERROR:gpu_command_buffer_stub.cc(491)] : Failed to make context current.

I assume my inability to use WebGL has something to do with this, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix these issues. My GPU isn't blacklisted and my drivers, browser, and operating system are all up to date. In addition, WebGL works perfectly fine on Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Also try reinstalling Chrome.

Comment: Chrome reinstall worked. I should have known better. Drives me crazy how often this method of troubleshooting works.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check [this reference for WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists) as referenced by [Google's support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1220892?hl=en). It's disabled (by default) in some cases for stability and conformance purposes. However, it doesn't mean that the card doesn't support it at all. I believe you can enable/force enable them, depending on the situation.

Comment: As I said in my original post, my GPU isn't blacklisted. I've also tried adding the "ignore blacklist" flag to chrome.exe

Comment: @J4G Then place a link on your post. You never mentioned which list you referred to.

Comment: Did the specifications I listed in detail not give you enough information to determine that my GPU wasn't on the blacklist?